# Add a criteria to date range for Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Currently using this formula

=SUMIFS('Raw Data'!D2:D8,'Raw Data'!C2:C8,">="&G3,'Raw Data'!C2:C8,"<="&H3)

I want to add this criteria:

Todd = 'Raw Data'!A2:A8

Sp add if it's within date range and the A column has the name Todd in it.

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!$A2:$A500,A2,'Raw Data'!$C2:$C500,">="&$G3,'Raw Data'!$C2:$C500,"<="&$H3)

Changed to Countifs statement and added new criteria.